Persist runtime config files in Azure App Services during Azure Maintenance
My team deploys docker-compose apps on Azure App Services.  However, Microsoft undergoes random maintenance and brings down the app services momentarily.  When this occurs, we lose some critical config files that are loaded during runtime.  These files are stored into the containers, but Microsoft's maintenance destroys the containers and rebuilds them, causing these files to be lost.
My question is, how do I ensure my files are not destroyed during the Microsoft maintenances?
One solution offered was to host the Docker compose in a VM rather than App service, but updating a VM with a new docker-compose requires much more time.
Another suggestion is to deploy a redundant app service, but this will double the costs.
Is there a cheaper alternative?

As per MS, you can enable persistent storage by setting the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE app setting to TRUE. Then, you can modify your docker-compose.yml file to map the file system to a directory within the container that is mapped to persistent storage for your app. This way, your config files will be stored in persistent storage and will not be lost during maintenance events.

Found these supporting docs from MS- Tutorial: Create a multi-container (preview) app in Web App for Containers - Add persistent storage

Common web application architectures - Monolithic applications and containers


Sorry, I just saw this.  The WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE item is very interesting, I will test it out.
